# Securely share keystore from master CI server

Tags: security, build, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

Is there a way to securely store a signing keystore with TeamCity on the master CI machine and use it on any build agent (that performs the actual build) so that the keystore does not need to be copied to each build agent?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

The [SSH key management](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/SSH+Keys+Management) is supported in TeamCity. You can upload an SSH private key into a project via UI and then use it in VCS roots configuration. The key will be passed to the agent if agent-side checkout is used.
If you need to store keys not for VCS roots only, then please comment/vote for the request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-45181.